# setInterval() при вызове повторно исполняется с увеличенной скоростью

Tags: javascript

Нужно чтобы при повторном вызове сохранялась работа и предыдущего вызова, и выполнялся новый

```js
 //empty array for display in div
    var mas = [];

    //start index
    var currentPosition = 0;

    //count of press button to add '1'
    var countOfStarting = 0;

    //container for indexes
    var arrayCurrentPosition = [currentPosition];

    //function for filling indexes
    function createCurrentPositions(countOfStarting) {
        arrayCurrentPosition[countOfStarting] = 0;
        return arrayCurrentPosition;
    }

    //onload filling array by '0'
    function onloadFillDiv(massive, fillDivCount) {
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < fillDivCount; i++) {
            massive[i] = 0;
        }
    }


    //for onload html displaying array to div element
    function onloadPrint(mas) {
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = mas;
    }

    function movingCurr(mas) {

        var curr = arrayCurrentPosition[countOfStarting];
        console.log(curr + " it is curr for" + countOfStarting + " - count of start")

        //'1' move to right from start of array or when meet '1'
        if (curr === 0 || mas[curr - 1] === 1
            && curr < mas.length - 1) {
            mas[curr] = 1;
            if (curr !== 0) {
                mas[curr - 1] = 0;
            }
            else {
                mas[curr + 1] = 0;
            }
            console.log(mas + "from movingCurr " + countOfStarting + "- count of start");
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = mas
            arrayCurrentPosition[countOfStarting]++;


        }
        else /* when (currentPosition === mas.length - 1 || mas[currentPosition + 1] === 1 && currentPosition > 0)*/ {

            //'1' move to the left from end of array or when meet '1'
            mas[curr] = 1;
            if (curr !== mas.length - 1) {
                mas[curr + 1] = 0;
            }
            else {
                mas[curr - 1] = 0;
            }
            console.log(mas + "from movingCurr");
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = mas
            arrayCurrentPosition[countOfStarting]--;

        }
    }


    function moving(mas) {

        if (currentPosition === 0 || mas[currentPosition - 1] === 1 && currentPosition < mas.length - 1) {
            mas[currentPosition] = 1;
            if (currentPosition !== 0) {
                mas[currentPosition - 1] = 0;
            }
            else {
                mas[currentPosition + 1] = 0;
            }

            console.log(mas + "from moving");
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = mas
            currentPosition++;
        }
        else /*(currentPosition === mas.length - 1 || mas[currentPosition + 1] === 1 && currentPosition > 0)*/ {
            mas[currentPosition] = 1;
            if (currentPosition !== mas.length - 1) {
                mas[currentPosition + 1] = 0;
            }
            else {
                mas[currentPosition - 1] = 0;
            }

            console.log(mas + "from moving");
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = mas
            currentPosition--;
        }
    }

    function start() {

        countOfStarting += 1;
        console.log(countOfStarting + "-count of starting")
        createCurrentPositions(countOfStarting);
        console.log(arrayCurrentPosition[countOfStarting] + " - curr position for " + countOfStarting + " countOfStarting")


        if (countOfStarting === 1) {
            setInterval(function () {
                moving(mas)
            }, 1000)
        }

        else {

            setInterval(function () {
                movingCurr(mas);
            }, 1000)
        }

        //clearInterval(b);
    }
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Level 2 Task</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="onloadFillDiv(mas,20),onloadPrint(mas)">

<form class="form-horizontal">
    <br>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <div id="output"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <button type="button" onclick="start()" class="btn btn-default">Add '1'</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
```

Помогите, как правильно организовать работу `setInterval()`? При запуске кнопки `Add` запускается метод `muveCurr()` с помощью функции `setInterval`, но при последующих нажатиях кнопки работа функции `muveCurr()` искажается и делается с уменьшенным интервалом времени.